# Connect jquery-script with waypoints JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-waypoints

I've included the [waypoints.js](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/) script on my site. Now I would like to connect this script with some jquery. The script should "start" if the content is in the viewport.

On a different site I used

```
$('.fly-in-animation').waypoint(function() {
              $(this.element).addClass('animated fadeInUp');
          }, { offset: '100%' });
```

But I've no idea how to connect the waypoints script with these jquery:

```
$({countNum: $('#counter-laender').text()}).animate({countNum: 14}, {
  duration: 2000,
  easing:'linear',
  step: function() {
    $('#counter-laender').text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
  },
  complete: function() {
    $('#counter-laender').text(this.countNum);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the sample code from [Waypoints site](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/) combined with what you provided (assuming you want this to happen when `#counter-laender` enters the viewport):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#counter-laender').waypoint(function() {
    myFunction();
  });
});

function myFunction() {
    $({
        countNum: $('#counter-laender').text()
    }).animate({
        countNum: 14
    }, {
        duration: 2000,
        easing: 'linear',
        step: function () {
            $('#counter-laender').text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
        },
        complete: function () {
            $('#counter-laender').text(this.countNum);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: No. Nothing appears. If I get rid of the first variable code `var waypoint = new Waypoint({
  element: document.getElementById('#counter-laender'),
  handler: function() {
    myFunction();
  }
});` the script doesn't work as well.

Comment: @JonasLoerken I edited the post, sorry for the delay. Try that new code. It's the simplest boilerplate for Waypoints that I can find. Is that still not working? Make sure the `myFunction()` or whatever you're using is correct itself. Try replacing it with an `alert()` or `console.log()` for testing.